# How do I mount an existing intel rst raid-5?

Tags: raid, fakeraid

I recently installed Linux Mint 18.1 and am dual booting alongside Windows 10. I have two RAID arrays that I want to access, but only one seems to work out of the box. One is a RAID-0 with two disks (my Windows system drives) and another is a RAID-5 with 4 disks. The RAID-0 volume is automatically detected, and I can mount it via Nemo, but I don't see the RAID-5 anywhere.

I've done a bit of research to try and figure this out, but I can't find anything that explains in a straightforward manner how to do this. I'm scared of destroying my array and losing data.

All I've found was instructions to run `dmraid -s` and `dmraid -r`. These list my volume and disks respectively, so they seem to be detected, but how do I mount the volume?

Here are some command outputs:

dmraid -s:

```
*** Group superset isw_cbfchdcibb
--> Active Subset
name   : isw_cbfchdcibb_Volume1
size   : 10557196032
stride : 256
type   : raid5_la
status : ok
subsets: 0
devs   : 4
spares : 0
```

dmraid -r:

```
/dev/sde: isw, "isw_cbfchdcibb", GROUP, ok, 7814037166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdc: isw, "isw_cbfchdcibb", GROUP, ok, 7814037166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdb: isw, "isw_cbfchdcibb", GROUP, ok, 7814037166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sda: isw, "isw_cbfchdcibb", GROUP, ok, 7814037166 sectors, data@ 0
```

ls -al /dev/mapper/*

```
crw------- 1 root root  10, 236 Mar  4 22:28 /dev/mapper/control
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 252,   0 Mar  4 22:28 /dev/mapper/isw_cbfchdcibb_Volume1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        7 Mar  4 22:28 /dev/mapper/isw_cbfchdcibb_Volume1p1 -> ../dm-1
```

Comment: sounds like an export problem: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/recipemovevgtonewsys.html  also reference the commands pvscan and vgimport in addition to vgexport, and vgchange.